# InvalidPathException when creating scala project from hello-world

Tags: scala, sbt

Following this procedure: https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

When I use the following command:

```
sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

I have the following error:

> $ sbt new scala/hello-world.g8 [error]
> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 118:
> ModuleType Version    Name
> ExportedCommands
> \Coursier\cache\v1 [error] Use 'last' for the full log. Project
> loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q

This error occurs even with the following command:

> $ sbt about [warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties,
> base directory: C:\Users\castelain.florianext\Documents\test\scala
> [error] java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index
> 118: ModuleType Version    Name
> ExportedCommands
> \Coursier\cache\v1 [error] Use 'last' for the full log. Project
> loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q

SBT version is: `sbt script version: 1.3.8`

How should I solve this ?

Comment: It seems there is an error with your installation related to Windows paths. May I recommend using **WSL** to install **Scala** instead of doing it directly over Windows?

Comment: Does the problem persist also with `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8`? If you are using powershell.exe does it work with [`-NoProfile`](https://github.com/dirs-dev/directories-jvm/issues/36)?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am on a company computer and do not have access to WSL

Comment: @MarioGalic Same problem with scala-seed as well as with -NoProfile.

Comment: Under which folder are you trying to create the `sbt` project? Is it under `/test` or `/scala`? Can you show what you already have under the directory where you are trying to create the project?

Comment: Can you  also share the result of doing `sbt -version` ?

Comment: @CristinaHG I try to create the project under ..../test/scala and the folder is empty.

Comment: @CristinaHG the output of `sbt -version` is `sbt script version: 1.3.8`

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining about not finding a sbt version within your `build.properties` file.

Try moving inside your `test/scala` empty folder, then type: `sbt sbtVersion`. That would set the current project to your `scala` folder, and should therefor create a `build.properties` with the sbt version set inside it.

Then you can try type again: `sbt new scala/hello-world.g8`.

Comment: With sbt 1.3.8, still the same error. With sbt 1.5.0, not the error but blocked by the proxy.

Comment: oh, yes I tried that out with sbt 1.4.9, not sure if that would also work with 1.3.8. Are you setting correctly all the java options required to use it behind a proxy? See in SBT docs https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Combined+Pages.html#HTTP%2FHTTPS%2FFTP+Proxy